# Summing up dynamic columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dynamic

I have an ever-growing dataframe, whereby the columns increase by rounds.
It currently looks like this:
[image]

My problem is finding a way to calculate the average of the last three "rounds" like in the picture, assuming that the rounds will increase.The columns (rounds) will have an incremental number.

Comment: what framwork are you using, pandas, pyspark, dask? please add the relevant tag. Also ideally add an actual example of your dataframe.

Comment: there's currently 6 columns but the no. of columns are increasing by rounds. There are 4 rows. The mean is clear, the question is how to find the mean of the last 3 rounds, say, knowing that the rounds are just numbers increasing in value by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a pandas DataFrame, going by the tags, you can use [.iloc()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({1: [10, 8, 3, 3], 2: [12, 10, 12, 1], 3: [11, 9, 8, 23], 4: [15, 16, 3, 11], 5: [14, 7, 5, 9]}, index=["John", "Peter", "Gary", "Mark"])
```

To just return a pandas Series of each:

```
df.mean(axis=1)
#Out: 
#John     12.4
#Peter    10.0
#Gary      6.2
#Mark      9.4
dtype: float64

df.iloc[:, -3:].mean(axis=1)
#Out: 
#John     13.333333
#Peter    10.666667
#Gary      5.333333
#Mark     14.333333
#dtype: float64
```

If you want to add columns to the end with your mean calculations:

```
df["mean"] = df.mean(axis=1)
df["mean of last 3"] = df.iloc[:, -4:-1].mean(axis=1)
```

Notice the .iloc index numbers are different in the second, because the "mean" column has been added to the end, so you want the first three of the last four columns.